# DECIMAL mysql and storage space?

Tags: mysql, decimal

From my understanding of the manual for `DECIMAL` in the mysql docs, it states that each multiple of nine digits requires 4 bytes and the following for left over digits;

```
number of digits leftover  |   bytes

0                          |   0
1                          |   1
2                          |   1
3                          |   2
4                          |   2
5                          |   3
6                          |   3
7                          |   4
8                          |   4
```

So a `decimal(12,6)` would be equal to 6 bytes in total storage?

I know that the fractional part will always equal 6 digits as zeros are padded, but the integer part is not so for a `DECIMAL(12,6)` column does the storage get valued per row or at column definition?

Example

```
    DECIMAL(12,6)
 1: 178.999999 // 3 digits for integer part so total would be 5 bytes?
 2: 0.880000 // 1 digits for integer part so total would be 4 bytes?
 3  123456.123456 // 6 digits would equal 6 bytes?
```

Or will it always be 6 bytes if declared `(12,6)`?

**EDIT**

Also a decimal declared as `(5,5)` would take 6 bytes to store and a decimal declared as `(12,6)` would also take 6 bytes to store. Seeing as the storage size is not an issue would the difference in size affect how mysql retrieves or indexes the column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For MySQL 5.1 (and higher), it splits up the storage for the integer part and the fractional part, and makes room for storage for the largest possibly number. So for a DECIMAL(12,6), you need 3 bytes for the integer part and 3 bytes for the fractional part. It doesn't look like it decreases storage based on the value; it sets the memory aside no matter what the value is.

You can check out the documentation here:

[MySQL Decimal Manual Page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
DECIMAL(12,6)
```

1: 178.999999 // 3 digits for integer part so total would be 5 bytes(Correct)
 2: 0.880000 // 1 digits for integer part so total would be 4 bytes?(Wrong)
 3  123456.123456 // 6 digits would equal 6 bytes?(Correct)

Explanation:
Leftover Digits Number of Bytes
0    0

1  1

2   1

3   2

4   2

5   3

6   3

7   4

8   4

and all multiples of 9 will contain 4 bytes

so 0.880000 will take 0 for integer part and 3 for fractional part hence 0+3=3

Answer (score 1):

It can be calculated with this function:

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `fn_DECIMAL_SIZE`(`M` INT, `D` INT) RETURNS int(11)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
set @m = m;
set @d = d;


set @i = @m-@d;

set @size =         4 * floor( @i/9 );
set @size = @size + ceil( (@i % 9) / 2 );

set @size = @size + 4 * floor( @d/9 );
set @size = @size + ceil( (@d % 9) / 2 );

return @size;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

[source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)

to create a list of some values use:

```sql
select m, d, fn_DECIMAL_SIZE(m,d)
from (
    (select seq as m from seq_1_to_20) _m
    join
    (select seq as d from seq_0_to_6) _d
)
where m>=d;
```